# Javascript Print function Breaks dropdown form submitting on change

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I'm  running two functions on the same page, one auto submits a single drop down form to update variables the other is used to print a section of the page. They both work as intended except after I use the print function it breaks the form submit function from working unless I reload the page. unsure why or how to resolve this.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#daterange').change(function() {
                this.form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function printDiv(printArea) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(printArea).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when you rewrite the document in printDiv function, jQuery looses the context of the onchange event binded here:

```
$(function() {
    $('#daterange').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

One possible workaround to tackle this is to bind the onChange event on dynamically created elements using something like this:

```
$(document).change('#daterange', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //this.form.submit(); // 'this' is now referring to document thus this.form is undefined.
    this.forms[0].submit(); // refer to your form here. this is just an example for reference
    //alert('submit called');
});
```

Notice the `$(document).change('#daterange', function(e) {` part, here we are telling jquery to bind the event with document and then look for the `#daterange` element whenever the value is updated.
The first parameter in .change tells jQuery to look for elements after the event trigger and works with dynamically created elements as well.

Here is a pen for your reference https://codepen.io/abhisheksharma14/pen/NWrmbGg

Comment: For reference: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler
Look for "Delegated event handlers" section

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept if that solves your problem :)

Comment: I tried this and the post doesnt submit at all now when using your suggested function

Comment: You need to update `this.form.submit();` to refer to your form. value of `this` has changed